# Unscored loaf is sealing up

Tags: baking, bread, sourdough

I'd like to do an unscored loaf of bread where instead of scoring you let it burst along the seams. The examples I've seen say you proof it seam down. The problem is that I tried this and the seams closed up completely. I baked it anyway and got a brick out of it. The loaf did burst at places on top but not at the seams.

What is the trick to actually getting this to work? I proofed for a couple of hours and then retarded in the fridge for about 12 hours.

Does this style only work if you do not retard?

Comment: Seams should be sealed up--at least somewhat--but that has no affect on why you got a "brick" of a loaf. That comes from baking it too long. So your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please go into detail on your recipe and method. Are you baking with steam?

Answer (score 1):

An unescorted loaf of bread, in a loaf pan, generally bursts along the top of the loaf pan.  If you want a "burst" look you need to score the area you want a burst using a razor blade or sharp knife.

Are you making a no-knead loaf in a Dutch oven?  They generally burst along the shaggy seams.

Rob is right, scoring and bread turning into a brick are not really related.